# Adding a "but NOT" statement to an Outlook rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I have set up a variety of rules for my Exchange account in Outlook. One of these being that all emails sent directly to me in the **To** field are added to a specific folder. However I also have a folder where auto generated emails for a discussion thread I'm a member of go, the rule for this folder is specified to gather all emails sent from a specific **noreply** address. Problem is though that these emails are also addressed directly to me, what happens is that the email becomes duplicated and one instance goes to the desired folder and another one ends up in my **To me** folder.

I want to set up a rule that tells my **To me** folder to only accept emails that are addressed to me but **NOT** emails sent from this **noreply** address.  But I don't seem to find any **NOT** statement in the rule editor.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: There is an exceptions option within the rules but, generally, this feature is lacking. It is possible to write your own VBa to do this though.

Comment: @DaveRook Thanks, I don't seem to find the exception option you were talking about. Is it in the same list as the "fulfil statements"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new rule:

1. Select `Start from a blank rule`, `Check messages when they arrive`. Select `Next >`.
2. Select the `sent only to me` or the `where my name is int the To box` depending on what you are looking for the rule to do. Select `Next >`.
3. Select the `move it to the specified folder` action. Pick the folder you want to file these messages in. Select `Next >`.
4. Select the `except if from people or distribution list` exception. Specify the noreply address. Select `Finish`.

Alternatively, place your existing rule for the noreply address ahead of the other in the rules list, and add the `stop processing more rules` action.